# Using the replace function to change value in R

Tags: r, replace

The replace () help info is very basic and contains no examples. 
Say I have the following

```
ages <- sample(40:80, 10, replace = T)
weights <- 100 + ages*.2 + rnorm(10, 0 , 20)
type <- sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = T)
grouping <- data.frame(ages,weights,type)
```

It may look like

```
   ages   weights type
1    49  81.27546    c
2    71 116.50149    c
3    67 152.14525    b
4    45 135.75849    c
5    72 114.35790    a
6    46 110.36591    a
7    40 106.16965    c
8    77 126.09591    c
9    44 107.28003    a
10   69  96.06653    b
```

I want to change the 'type' value in row 9 from 'a' to 'z'. I have looked to use the following commands, but neither has worked

```
replace(grouping$type[9],values = "z")
```

OR

```
grouping$type[9] <- z
```

Comment: There is in help(replace) :  "Note:

x is unchanged: remember to assign the result." So you didn't remember. R is a functional language. You need to assign the results of functions.

Comment: Your replace line doesn't work because you are not using the right syntax `replace(x, list, values)`. Second line doesn't work because you are assigning an expression `z` that is not defined. If you wrap a set of quotes around `z` to make it a character; it still wouldn't work because you are trying to introduce a new level to the factor column `type`.

Comment: this can be done without replace: `grouping$type[grouping$type == 'a'] <- 'z'`; is there some reason you want to use replace instead?

Comment: @rawr, he can't do that because `type` is a `factor`

Comment: oh true, I should have checked my options settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by doing this

```
levels(grouping$type) <- c(levels(grouping$type), "z")  # adding new level "z"
grouping$type[9] <- "z"                                 # changing a to z
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just make `data.frame` not to convert your `character` type variables to factors by default, by setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
grouping <- data.frame(ages,weights,type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then

```
grouping$type[9] <- "z"
```

Will work as expected